# Can I solve an optization problem by solving directly the KKT conditions instead of the pertubed KKT in primal-dual interior point method?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

I encountered the following problem in studying convex optimization:
In order to solve the convex optimization problem
$$\begin{cases}
\mathrm{min}\ f(x)\\\mathrm {s.t.}\ g_i(x)\leq0\ (i=1,...,m)\
\end{cases}
(1)$$
One needs to solve the KKT condition equations:
$$\begin{cases}
\nabla f(x)+\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i \nabla g_i(x)+\mu ^T(Ax-b)=0\\
g_i(x)\leq0\\
\lambda_i\geq0\\
\lambda_i g_i(x) = 0
\end{cases}
(2)$$
However, in the primal-dual interior point method, the pertubed KKT condition equations are solved (in which the parameter $t$ is updated during iterations):
$$\begin{cases}
\nabla f(x)+\sum_{i=1}^m \lambda_i \nabla g_i(x)+\mu ^T(Ax-b)=0\\
g_i(x)\leq0\\
\lambda_i\geq0\\
\lambda_i g_i(x) = -1/t
\end{cases}
(3)$$
I can understand that the pertubed KKT condition is constructed under the inspiration of barrier interior point method (in which the problem $\mathrm{min}\ f(x)-1/t\sum_{i=1}^m\log {(-g_i(x))}$ is solved). However, my problem is,

> What is the numerical advantage of solving problem (1) by solving Eq. (3) rather than Eq. (2)?

I see no difference between solving Eq. (2) and Eq. (3), while Eq. (2) is definitely easier to solve (at least no need to update $t$)...

Comment: There is a slight error: Either system $(2)$ and $(3)$ do not need the $\mu^T(Ax-b)$ part, or system $(1)$ needs an additional condition of $Ax=b$.